# Excel - Delete Rows From Sheet 1 Based on Values From Sheet 2

Tags: vba, excel

**Scenario:**

Sheet 1 "Client Records" contains client details for c. 4000 clients in rows, (i.e. name, telephone number, email, address), one client per row.

Sheet 2 "Invalid Numbers" contains just one column, which is a list of telephone numbers which are now known to be Invalid and no longer working.

**Requirement:**

Automatically go through Sheet 1 and (completely) delete any client record (i.e. row) which contains a telephone number (i.e. in column 2) which matches any of the telephone numbers listed in Sheet 2 "Invalid Numbers"

**Result:**

Sheet 1 will be a list of Client Records having deleted all the records that had Invalid numbers in them.

I found the following code on StackOverflow but the problem is that I have no idea how to program it in or use it?! I am using Excel for Mac 2011.

```
Public Sub delete_selected_rows()
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rngToDel As Range, c As Range
    Dim lastRow as Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row  
        Set rng1 = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    End With

    Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")

    For Each c In rng1
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, rng2, 0)) Then
            'if value from rng1 is found in rng2 then remember this cell for deleting
            If rngToDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rngToDel = c
            Else
                Set rngToDel = Union(rngToDel, c)
            End If
        End If
    Next c

    If Not rngToDel Is Nothing Then rngToDel.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Could anyone show me how to do this or if above code is correct for my job, how to actually input it into Excel and run it? I'm simply starting with the workbook open and the two sheets sitting there!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the above code is work fine for your requirement. But you need to change small part according to your scenario your phone no is in column B in sheet1 so you need to change bellow part
`Set rng1 = .Range("B2:B" & lastRow)`

you have to paste the code in Visual basic editor to open in mac please refer this link [Click here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/visual_basic_editor2011.php)

Comment: Actually, unfortunately I am still confused! I managed of course to open the Editor but I have no idea how to save the code as a Macro that can appear in a special menu I have in my Excel (called My Custom Tools ... I have another two macros in that menu which someone created for me years ago). Can someone please help?